# What's the context of use of the word kudos?

Tags: etymology

What's the origin and context of use of the word **kudos**?

I think these phrases are similar:

```
Kudos for you
Karma for you
Points for you
```

The first time I read kudos was playing [Metropolis Street Racer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_Street_Racer#Kudos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etymonline has [this to say](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=kudos&searchmode=none) about *kudos*:

> "fame, renown," 1799, from Gk. kyddos "glory, fame, renown," from kydos "glory, fame," lit. "that which is heard of" (see caveat). A singular noun in Gk., but the final -s often is mistaken as a plural suffix in English, leading to the barbarous back-formation kudo (first attested 1941).

Especially note the singular vs. plural issue.

The normal preposition to use with it is *to* and it can be used without a preposition as well when it is used as a direct object, as in [these examples](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kudos):

1. Kudos to everyone who helped.
2. The company has earned kudos for responding so quickly to customers' concerns.